# set crontab in ubuntu for helm upgrade

Tags: cron

I want to using crontab to auto run file.sh for helm in kubernetes, but when file.sh run , this still have log but helm command not run , is anyone using can help me, thanks you this is my crontab set:

```
* * * * * cd /home/x/internet-update && bash internet-crawler-update.sh >> /home/x/deploy1.log
```

Comment: The No.1 issue with things like this is that cron doesn't provide a suitable environment for running the script (most often, it relies on executables that are not in the cron `PATH`) - without knowing what `internet-crawler-update.sh` contains it's hard to be more specific

Comment: my internet-crawler-update.sh just only contains this: helm install internet-crawler-service-aic --kube-context=delta --set image.tag=2.9.3 --values=/home/x/internet-update/internet-crawler-service-aic/values-prod.yaml --timeout 30 --name internet-crawler-service-aic

Comment: Please use the [edit] button below your question to add this information

Comment: The `cron` command parameter is NOT `bash`. Use it to call a `bash` script where you can easily control your environment.